# Customize closing Tag using Dart XML - </mxCell>

Tags: xml, flutter, dart

```
      builder.element(
              'mxCell'
              ' '
              'id= "${myId}"'
              ' '
              'value=""'
              ' '
              'style="outlineConnect=0;dashed=0;verticalLabelPosition=bottom;verticalAlign=top;align=center;html=1;shape=${_myObjects[i]};fillColor=#F58534;gradientColor=none;"'
              ' '
              'vertex="1"'
              ' '
              'parent="1"', nest: () {
            builder.element('mxGeometry'
                ' '
                'x= "${_myObjects[i + 1]}"'
                ' '
                'y= "${_myObjects[i + 2]}"'
                ' '
                'width= "${_myObjects[i + 3]}"'
                ' '
                'height= "${_myObjects[i + 4]}"'
                ' '
                'as="geometry"');
          })
```

I am generating xml from strings using Dart xml builder.element.  My challenge is that the closing tags include all the properties in the opening tags. I am trying to just get the closing tags by itself.

```
//Output
<mxCell id= "135" value="" style="outlineConnect=0;dashed=0;verticalLabelPosition=bottom;verticalAlign=top;align=center;html=1;shape=mxgraph.aws3.s3;fillColor=#F58534;gradientColor=none;" vertex="1" parent="1">
                        <mxGeometry x= "40.56576085090637" y= "87.17634147405622" width= "360.3372859954834" height= "494.9196102619171" as="geometry"/>
                    "</mxCell id= "135" value="" style="outlineConnect=0;dashed=0;verticalLabelPosition=bottom;verticalAlign=top;align=center;html=1;shape=mxgraph.aws3.s3;fillColor=#F58534;gradientColor=none;" vertex="1" parent="1">"
```

```
//Desired output
<mxCell id= "135" value="" style="outlineConnect=0;dashed=0;verticalLabelPosition=bottom;verticalAlign=top;align=center;html=1;shape=mxgraph.aws3.s3;fillColor=#F58534;gradientColor=none;" vertex="1" parent="1">
                        <mxGeometry x= "40.56576085090637" y= "87.17634147405622" width= "360.3372859954834" height= "494.9196102619171" as="geometry"/>
                    </mxCell>
```

The closing tags include the elements in the opening tag. I want it to be just the name of the tag without it properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about package:xml in the pub, I can see that you ended up putting everything as the name of the tag, so of course it's going to repeat it in the close tag.  You want something closer to this:

```
final builder = XmlBuilder();
builder.processing('xml', 'version="1.0"');
builder.element('bookshelf', nest: () {
  builder.element('book', nest: () {
    builder.element('title', nest: () {
      builder.attribute('lang', 'en');
      builder.text('Growing a Language');
    });
    builder.element('price', nest: 29.99);
  });
  builder.element('book', nest: () {
    builder.element('title', nest: () {
      builder.attribute('lang', 'en');
      builder.text('Learning XML');
    });
    builder.element('price', nest: 39.95);
  });
  builder.element('price', nest: 132.00);
});
final bookshelfXml = builder.buildDocument();
```

Note the use of builder.attribute, so that it appears as an attribute of the element in which it is within.

EDIT: (untested)

```
builder.element('mxCell', nest: () {
  builder.attribute('id', myId);
  builder.attribute('value', '');
  builder.attribute('style', 'outlineConnect=0;dashed=0;verticalLabelPosition=bottom;verticalAlign=top;align=center;html=1;shape=${_myObjects[i]};fillColor=#F58534;gradientColor=none;');
  builder.attribute('vertex', 1);
  builder.attribute('parent', 1);
})
```

Comment: Alternatively you can also use `builder.element('mxCell', attributes: {'id': myId, value: '', ...})`.

Comment: Bah.  I knew there was something easier.  Hi Lukas!  XML is another cool project with petitparser!  You are the parsemaster!